# restrict checkbox checking in a gridview table

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I am trying to show a compare button to user to compare selected rows in asp.net. This is what I have tried so far.

```
$(function () {
    $("#myTable").find("input:checkbox").click(function () {
        var bol = $("#myTable").find("input:checkbox:checked");
        alert(bol.length);
        if (bol.length <= 3) {
            $('#hello').fadeIn();
        } else if (bol.length > 1) {
            alert('hi');
            $('#error').hide();
        } else if (bol.length >= 4) {
            $("#myTable").find("input:checkbox").not(":checked").attr("disabled", bol);
        } else {
            $('#hello').hide();
        }
    });
    $('#compare').click(function () {
        var ck = $("#myTable").find("input:checkbox:checked");
        if (ck.length === 1) {
            $('#error').show();
        } else if (ck.length > 1) {
            $('#error').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Now, I want to hide the `#error` id if the user ticked more than one checkbox which is not happening right now.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ravimallya/H35YG/)**

I tried with this also, but it's not enabling checkboxes, if we selected any 4 checkboxes and then unchecked any one.

```
$(function () {
    $("#myTable").find("input:checkbox").click(function () {
        var bol = $("#myTable").find("input:checkbox:checked");
        if (bol.length <= 3) {
            $('#error').hide();
            $('#hello').fadeIn();
        } else if (bol.length >= 4) {
            $("#myTable").find("input:checkbox")
                .not(":checked").attr("disabled", bol);
        } else {
            $('#hello').hide();
        }
    });
    $('#compare').click(function () {
        var ck = $("#myTable").find("input:checkbox:checked");
        if (ck.length === 1) {
            $('#error').show();
        }
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ravimallya/H35YG/2/)**

Comment: The fiddle seems to work for me.  Which browser are you using?

Comment: in win7 chrome. http://fiddle.jshell.net/ravimallya/H35YG/show/ here also not working. no errors though...

Comment: @Ravimallya Is this what you want --> http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/H35YG/4/

Comment: @TusharGupta. No, but see my answer. I was able to fix it myself. hardly struggled for 2 hours before posting question.

Comment: @Ravimallya See --> you might like --> http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/H35YG/6/

Comment: Yeah okay. Nice approach. but i don't want to show the error without clicking on the compare button, and the error is not hiding after unchecking all checkboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue.  here is the solution. Answering my question as it may be helpful to someone.

```
$(function () {
    // Just pass the gridview id or class name where it has checkbox in header as well as in each row. Also, define num to restrict maximum number of checkboxes, that needed to be checked.
    var grd = $('.mGrid');
    var num = 4;
    var count = 0;
    var headChk = grd.find('th>input:checkbox');
    var checks = grd.find('td>input:checkbox');
    $(headChk).change(function () {
        if ($(headChk).is(':checked')) {
            for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                $(checks[i]).prop("checked", true);
            }
        } else {
            $(checks).prop("checked", false);
        }
    });
    // to check or uncheck top selector
    $(checks).change(function () {
        var bol = grd.find("td>input:checkbox:checked");
        var b = grd.find("td>input:checkbox");
        var a = bol.length;
        var c = (b.length);
        if (a > num) {
            alert("Can't select more than " + num + " items");
            $(this).prop("checked", false);
        } else if (a == num) {
            $(headChk).prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            $(headChk).prop("checked", false);
        }
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ravimallya/5gLMW/)**